# RoboCopy /minlad not working

Tags: robocopy

Trying to use robocopy to move folders that haven’t been modified in 24 hours, with some exclusions. But when executed, all the folders bar the exclusions are moved, this means that folders that have been modified in the last 24 hours are moved as well,
I’ve tried also tried /minage to try and test if it was just me, but there was no difference.
I removed the full file paths as they included my full name

```
    robocopy C:\File1 C:\2Delete *.* /E /XD C:\2Delete /move /MINLAD:1 /Xd "C:\Other" /Xd "C:\Public" /Xd "C:\Default" pause
```